# QListView with row background in two different colors

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qlistview

I use `QListView` (in PyQt5) to display strings.
I want to have the background color of each item in that list changing between two colors to make it easier to read.

I tried `Qt.DecorationRole` but this only create an "icon" on the left side of each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self. listWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True) this will give you Alternate color for each row.

Comment: Setting the color doesn't work. `palette = QPalette(); palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, Qt.yellow); self.setPalette(palette); self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)`. Any idea?

Comment: Mhm... Need to set `QPalette.Base`, too. Then it works. But I don't want to set this explicite. How can I get the current `QPalette.Base` color to set it.